# Caulking vinyl siding inside jchannel / post?

Tags: siding, caulk

Found I have some yellow jackets trying to get behind my siding in the j-channel/post at the end of the siding. Can I caulk up and down the entire length of the channel where the siding ends to close that gap off?

Not my picture but I would caulk along green. Yellow jackets trying to get into a gap similar to red.

[image]

Comment: It was my understanding that the siding needs to be free to move and breathe, but I'm not totally sure.  Can you use an insecticide or repellant in that crack instead?

Comment: @JPhi1618 is correct, just hand a couple of fake nests or inflated paper bags and that will keep the territorial monsters away.

Comment: Yea I hit the whole seam with Tempo and they have been dissuaded for the time being. Wanted a more permanent approach.

Comment: You've asked an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking whether a proposed solution would work, ask for a good solution to the actual problem.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a good idea. Vinyl siding expands and contracts quite a bit with temperature. By caulking it you prevent movement and could cause buckling or other warping. It would also look bad.

The insects would just find a new location and you'd end up doing it all over again. A better approach is to use aromatic deterrents. [More on that](https://www.goodhousekeeping.com/home/a20706019/how-to-keep-wasps-away/)

Comment: ended up using a puffer with insecticide and/or diatomaceous earth